# How to create logic with String updated when he is changed

Tags: java, android

I Mean about something like

Win/Lost game

When I  win, I got money and my account is changed from 5000 to 5200, but when I win next time I got once again 5200.

I know what is issue, but I dont know how to resolve it.

Here is my code for change text when WIN happen

```
String text = spinnerData.getSelectedItem().toString();  //i get data from spinner
int temp = Integer.parseInt(text); //then i parseit to Int
int temp2 = (temp*2); //profit 100% so *2
btnCashCurrency.setText((5000 + temp2) + " $"); //and here i change text
```

But this work like. when in spinner is 200. my text will change to 5200, but then when I make spinner 100 my text will change to 5100.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always add your profit to hardcoded 5000 instead of saving your current amount and adding it to that.

Try that:

```
// Define this as global variable
int cash = 5000

// When win:
String text = spinnerData.getSelectedItem().toString();  //i get data from spinner
int temp = Integer.parseInt(text); //then parse it to Int
int temp2 = temp * 2; //profit 100% so *2
cash += temp2 //Add the amount to cash
btnCashCurrency.setText(cash + " $");
```